# How to copy/clone a mongodb collection to another one?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I'm trying to copy a collection(huge or small) to another collection in the same mongo database using spring-data.

Every solution I found, was deprecated or wasn't working.
I tried this one who seem the best for my need:

```
    mongoTemplate.getCollection("oneCollection").aggregate(Arrays.asList(new Document("$out","otherCollection")));
```

But it doesn't do anything, no error, no action on the database.

Do you have any solution for copying a collection easily using spring-data ?

Comment: which version of mongodb are you using?

Comment: I'm on 4.0.6 mongodb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
OutOperation outOperation = new OutOperation("otherCollection");
mongoTemplate.aggregate(Aggregation.newAggregation(outOperation), "oneCollection", BasicDBObject.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that `OutOperation` currently **replace** the destination collection.
All the data already in this collection will be lost and replaced by this operation.
(Spring's `OutOperation` has an `OutMode`, but it is not supported by underlying mongo drivers, if someone has more info on this ?)

For those who would like to *insert* values into the destination collection, and not replace the whole collection:
Mongo 4.2 has [introduced](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/) a `$merge` operation.
It is called `MergeOperation` in [recent spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/aggregation/MergeOperation.html).

In order to use this new Operation, you might need to upgrade the *mongo drivers* to versions > 4.2. It won't work with `mongodb-driver-sync:4.0.5`, which may be the one pulled by Spring by default.

```
MergeOperation mergeOp = Aggregation.merge().intoCollection("othercollection").build();
mongoTemplate.aggregate(mergeOp, "originalcollection", BasicDBObject.class);
```

See also, `skipOutput()` [option](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/aggregation/AggregationOptions.Builder.html#skipOutput--).

Comment: Looks like `mergeOp` need to be mapped to a Aggregation: `Aggregation.newAggregation(mergeOp)`